# React Native Modal content outside of device's view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have the following `Modal` which I would like to have its content scrollable when it doesn't fit the screen. However, when the device's window is smaller the `Modal`'s content just overflows outside the view bounds of the device - some header is lost and also part of the footer.

How can I activate the scrollView so that the content is contained within the view bounds of the device?

```js
import { Modal, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

<Modal
  transparent
  animationType="fade"
  visible={modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    setModalVisibility(!modalVisible);
  }}>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.modalOuterContainer}>
    .....
  </ScrollView>
</Modal>
```

Edit:

For anyone having the same problem. A fix that I found was to set on a `View` inside the `Modal` the height to `height: Dimensions.get('window').height,`. As the modal appears to have absolute positioning, this may be the only approach.
However, one downside of this would be that on larger screens you would still end up taking all the space. When I have a fix that works properly I ll post an answer.

Comment: try wrapping the scrollview in a view with `flex: 1`

Comment: If I do that then it will now pop out like a modal and it will push everything else lower as the view probably doesn t have the same positioning

Comment: The view will not push anything lower as it's inside the modal.

Comment: Misread wrap the Modal. I've tried that as well and the header is still outside of the device's screen.

Answer (score 3):

The solution which works fine for my case was to have a `View` element inside the `Modal` with `maxHeight` set to `maxHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height - 50,`. I used the `-50` just to also have some margins, but it's not necessary.

```
import { Modal, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

<Modal
  transparent
  animationType="fade"
  visible={modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    setModalVisibility(!modalVisible);
  }}>
 <View style={{maxHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height - 50}}
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.modalOuterContainer}>
    .....
  </ScrollView>
 </View>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert Model inside a parent view & style parent view according to your requirements.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";

class ModalExample extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: true
  };

  setModalVisibility = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: this.state.modalVisible
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Modal
          animationType="fade"
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={this.setModalVisibility}
        >
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.modalOuterContainer}>
              ...
          </ScrollView>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this approach on a device with a small screen? I'm using the Android Emulator - 3.3_WQVGA and it does not work.